# I am trying to convert json object into a csv object

Tags: json, pandas, csv

```
r_vehicles = requests.post(API)) 
df_vehicles = pd.read_json(r_vehicles.text)

df_v = pd.DataFrame(r_v)
df_v = pd.to_csv(df_v)

r_v = requests.post("Api"))
df_v = pd.read_json(r_v.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

pandas comes with functions to read a JSON into a dataframe and also to export a dataframe as a CSV

JSON -> dataframe -> CSV is what the below code does.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_json("YOURJSON.json")
df.to_csv('YOURCSV.csv')
```

Comment: any other comment/context to share with us why your answer should work? Only that way we can learn now and in the future.